# How can I improve Elasticsearch performance for sorted and geographically filtered queries over large datasets?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a large dataset of relatively short documents which include, among other fields, a given name, a family name, a tenantId, a geographic location, and a set of skills.

We have roughly 7 million records spread over three nodes, and things are unbearably slow (on the order of ten seconds) when searching for a term with a decent number of matches. We will usually be sorting our result set alphabetically by name, chronologically by createdDate, or by term relevance. We also require term highlights and result counts. We are using the REST api to communicate with ES.

I've read that sorting can be a major bottleneck for search performance; what are some strategies that have worked in production to deal with this kind of requirement?

I'm using a mapping similar to the following:

```
"candidate": {
"dynamic":"true",
"properties": {
  "accountId": {
    "type": "string",
    "store": "true",
    "index": "not_analyzed"
  },
  "tenant": {
    "type": "string",
    "store": "true",
    "index": "not_analyzed"
  },
  "givenName": {
    "type": "string",
    "store": "true",
    "index":"analyzed",
    "analyzer":"sortable",
    "term_vector" : "with_positions_offsets"
  },
  ...
  "locations": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "string",
        "store": "true",
        "index": "analyzed",
        "term_vector" : "with_positions_offsets"
      },
      "point": {
        "type" : "geo_point",
        "store": "true",
        "lat_lon":"true"
      }
    }
  },
  "skills": {
    "type": "string",
    "store": "true",
    "index": "analyzed",
    "term_vector" : "with_positions_offsets"
  },
  "createdDate": {
    "type": "long",
    "store": "true",
    "index": "not_analyzed"
  },
  "updatedDate": {
    "type": "long",
    "store": "true",
    "index": "not_analyzed"
  }
}
```

And queries structured like this:

```
{
  "from" : 0,
  "size" : 40,
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : {
        "bool" : {
          "should" : [ {
            "multi_match" : {
              "query" : "query text",
              "fields" : [ "givenName", "familyName", "email", "locations.name", "skills"],
              "type" : "cross_fields"
            }
          }, {
            "prefix" : {
              "email" : {
                "prefix" : "query text"
              }
            }
          } ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "post_filter" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : {
        "geo_polygon" : {
          "point" : {
            "points" : [ [ -75.06681499999999, 40.536544 ], 
            ... many more long/lat points ... 
            [ -75.06681499999999, 40.536544 ] ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort" : [ {
    "createdDate" : {
      "order" : "asc"
    }
  } ],
  "highlight" : {
    "fields" : {
      "givenName" : { },
      "familyName" : { },
      "email" : { },
      "locations.name" : { },
      "skills" : { }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there some kind of range-based querying solution that others have found helpful for dealing with similar sort/search requirements?

Comment: Have you tried removing parts of the query (highlights, sorting, etc) to see what exactly is slowing your query down? The values in the field data cache are used for sorting, if the field data cache doesn't have enough RAM assigned it will result in slower queries.

Comment: Have you tried to move the filter from the post_filter to the query? You could use a filtered query to do that. Indeed, I don't know if the sorting is done after the filtering, or before which could have an impact on the performance of this request.

Comment: @DanTuffery Removing either speeds up the query, and removing both speeds it up immensely. The problem is that their functionality is a business requirement, so I'm looking for ways to achieve it more efficiently.

Comment: @Tom83 Good idea; moved that over and am seeing some performance gains locally, but will have to try it on our larger dataset to know for sure.

Comment: Do you use the same points each time for the polygon filter? This one is not cached by default, so you could set _cache to true.

Comment: @Tom83 We feed in polygons representing location boundaries, which do not change. I'm experimenting with cacheing them with the location name as the cache key today.